# Anchor tag buttons don't change the font color and variables do not work

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I'm trying to change font color of `<a>` but it doesn't work. Also background color change doesn't work. I already tried to use hexadecimal notation but it also doesn't work. I also tried to style `.btn` without pseudo-classes but it also doesn't work.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ghavaze/pen/XWpPjgN)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Big+Shoulders+Display:wght@700&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap');

:root{
    --bright-orange: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
    --dark-cyan: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
    --very-dark-cyan: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
    --transparent-white: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
    --very-light-gray: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    font-size: 15px;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn:any-link{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid var(--very-light-gray);
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: var(--very-light-gray);
    font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn--1:any-link{
    color: var(--bright-orange);
}
.btn--2:any-link{
    color: var(--dark-cyan);
}
.btn--3:any-link{
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:active{
    color: var(--very-light-gray);
}
.btn--1:hover,
.btn--1:active{
    background: var(--bright-orange);
}
.btn--2:hover,
.btn--2:active{
    background: var(--dark-cyan);
}
.btn--3:hover,
.btn--3:active{
    background: var(--very-dark-cyan);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn--3 showcase__btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
<a class="btn btn--3 showcase__btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
<a class="btn btn--3 showcase__btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
```

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to actually change? Where have you changed the anchor colour in the CSS? What did you change it to? Did you upload to your server and refresh your browser? "it doesn't work" is not a helpful diagnosis of the issue. Thanks

Comment: Do you realise you have 3 buttons with the class `btn--3` but none with the other classes? Perhaps you mean to update your HTML to associate the correct classes with the correct buttons?

Comment: Also you do not need :any-link on every element, it doesn't work like that. You don't need it at all because every anchor is `.btn` so that catches all the anchors.

Comment: @Martin I didn't realize that I have 3 elements with the same class in HTML. Thank you! Could you please clarify  what do you mean with this :any-link pseudo-class? Should I remove it?  Hould I leave it only at `.btn`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it like this:

```
.btn{  
  color: var(--dark-cyan) 
}
```

Like @Martin said, you don't need the `:any-link`. For exact info. look at this: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any-link).

Comment: So when should one use the `:any-link`?

Comment: Hm, for exact infos look at this: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any-link). :any-link is a pseudo-class selector. You could actually use it, but in your example it is not needed.